# How to convert PCollection of Strings to TableRows?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying a to create a very simple Beam pipeline that takes a PubSub message and writes it to BigQuery.  The message comes in as a string, and I need to convert it to a TableRow to write it to BigQuery.  I, for the life of me, can't find an easy way to do that.  My table is just a single column at this point.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you having difficulty with writing a function to convert a single String to a TableRow, or with applying this function to a PCollection<String> to obtain PCollection<TableRow>?

Comment: The former. I've figured out how to use the function to apply the transform.... I just can't figure out the function itself.

Comment: Have you looked at the example in the javadoc of BigQueryIO.write() https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L946 ? It's basically just "new TableRow().set("columnName", value).set("otherColumn", value)" etc.

Comment: No, I hadn't seen that - I think that works (or least the compiler gets past that.  Thank you!

Comment: Great, I've converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the example in the [javadoc of BigQueryIO.write()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#write--).

The syntax is: `new TableRow().set("columnName", value).set("otherColumn", value)` etc.